# Bold letters in input

Tags: formatting

When I want to typeset a greek letter  I type

```
esc a esc
```

but as I want to use majuscules as names, I cannot make a distinction between say matrix and scalars. So, is there a simple way to use bold letters in an input line?

Comment: Input cells font is already Bold. As I understand the question, yes, you could define special rules manualy or using Notation package so that some symbols are recognized and/or printed with custom style but that doesn't seem as worth the effort.

Comment: Not so sure. For instance, in LaTeX, I can use many fonts in mathematics. The problem is not only for programming but also because one can use Ma like a Text editor

Comment: So your question is how to make the selected font thicker? Take a look at Palettes / Writing Assistant

Comment: I have tried but it doesn't work in math mode. Maybe I am wrong but an other use is this one : when I want to define a matrix $\textbf{x}$, I want that its element be $x_{i,j}$. But if I do that I have a message with a recursion limit, because the symbol to define  the matrix is th same that the symbol to define its elements. So I have a a matrix with x elements

Comment: Don't use names with not meaning, there is no "math mode" in mathematica. And you said last time you are interested in text editor intaraction. Now you want to define the matrix. Sorry, I don't know what is your point.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer to write `xv` for a vector `x` and `xm` for a matrix.

You can then define e.g.

```
xm = Array[x, {2, 2}]

(* Out[525]= {{x[1, 1], x[1, 2]}, {x[2, 1], x[2, 2]}} *)
```

You could even define

```
X = Array[x, {2, 2}]

(* Out[526]= {{x[1, 1], x[1, 2]}, {x[2, 1], x[2, 2]}} *)
```

Notice, however, that the use of capitial letters at the beginning of a user defined function or variable is against the rules of Mathematica and should definitely be avoided.